# Etymology of the word "pole"?

Tags: complex-analysis, terminology

In his book *Control System Design*, Bernard Friedland writes (section 4.2, page 115):

> The roots of the denominator [of a rational function] are called the *poles* of the transfer function because $H(s)$ becomes infinite at these complex frequencies and **a contour map of the complex plane appears as if it has poles sticking up from these points**.

Is there any historical legitimacy to this explanation of the origin of the word "pole" to describe a root of the denominator of a rational function?

Comment: I always thought that poles come from electric poles which are singularities of the electric force, that is, a place where a function becomes infinite.

Comment: I don't see any direct math-history connection when looking at: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=pole&allowed_in_frame=0, or it's very convoluted? lhf's logic seems sound?

Comment: @lhf What do you mean by 'electric pole'?  a point charge?

Comment: @TobinFricke, yes, sorry for the noise. I probably mixed it with *magnetic pole*.

Comment: Yes, I guess the word 'pole' is probably related to its usage in *monopole*, *dipole*, ..., *multipole*, etc.

Comment: The word 'pole' has an entry in Jeff Miller's list (which is oft-referenced around here): http://jeff560.tripod.com/p.html

Comment: This question also has other references to check: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/19397/a-place-to-learn-about-math-etymology